# “If you didn’t know”correct usage

Tags: grammar

> I’ve always considered you my best friend if you didn’t know.

Is the above sentence correct?
If so, where did “if v2, would v1” go?
If not, what would be the sentence with the most similar meaning to that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’ve always considered you my best friend, if you didn’t know.

is perfectly correct. One could also say

> I’ve always considered you my best friend, in case you didn’t know.

In both the comma after "friend" is needed, I think.

This is simply a different form from “if v2, would v1”.